# Find missing numbers in continuous filenames (advanced ls & find)

Tags: linux, command-line, ls

Let's say I have a script that generates incrementing folder names over time (100, 101, 102, 103, 104, etc...). These folders are synced between machines and there is a chance of creation failure for any given folder on system 2.

System 1 is always in sync:
100/
101/
102/
103/
104/
etc...

System 2 may have errors:
100/
102/
103/
etc...

(as you can see, 101/ & 104/ are missing on system 2)

**How can I generate a list of all the missing folders on System 2?**

P.S.
Rsync is not really an option because the actual number of folders is incredibly high.

Comment: are both directories accessible from a single machine or do you need a cross-machine solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe the contents of `ls` on each machine to a file, and then diff the two files. You can also use the command `comm` to show lines that are only in one file, and not in the other.

Comment: ls should keep things sorted, but just in case it isn't or the sorting is different on the two hosts, you can pipe the output to sort.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
% ls -1 System1 > ls.System1            # Use the -1 flag to ensure 1 dir per line
% ls -1 System2 > ls.System2
% comm -23 ls.System1 ls.System2
101
104
```

The comm command can show you what is common to both, unique to f1, or unique to f2:

```
comm -12 f1 f2  # common to both
comm -23 f1 f2  # unique to f1
comm -13 f1 f2  # unique to f2
```

Answer (score 0):

just generate a list of successful creations as they occur

Answer (score 0):

you can use diff. assuming you had already mapped system2 to a path

```
diff system1/path system2/path
```